# add a user control to a form

Tags: vb.net

Hi there I have a user control in my project and I want to add this user control to a form when I click on a button.

This is the code I wrote:

```
Using GstAbonnement As New GestionAbonnement() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
            Panel1.Controls.Add(GstAbonnement)
End Using
```

The problem is when I click on the button nothing happens

Comment: Take the "Using" statement off. Let it just: Dim GstAbonnement As New GestionAbonnement() With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}

Comment: But I need my object to be disposed after I use it, In C# I tried the same as the above code an it worked perfectly !

Comment: Right, I might be wrong here but all objects created inside a using will be disposed when you leave it. So what you are doing is basically Creating a control, adding the control to the panel and then removing it completely. So with this code I pretty much expect the control to disappear, since it doesn't exist any more. Just do what J.Hudler wrote and dispose the control when you are done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Dim GstAbonnement As New GestionAbonnement()
GstAbonnement.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
Panel1.Controls.Add(GstAbonnement)
```

After you are done with the control, dispose it

```
GstAbonnement.Dispose()
```